# Weird VBA Expected End of Statement Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I started working on creating a custom function in Access 2010, using the VBA Editor, but I keep getting an Expected End of Statement Error.

Here's the code:

```
Public Function getPayTotal(ByVal StudentID As Long) As Long

Return StudentID

End Function
```

I have absolutely no idea why this isn't working. The debug keeps sending me back to the Return StudentID line. Am I over looking something incredibly simple?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not return:

```
Public Function getPayTotal(ByVal StudentID As Long) As Long

   getPayTotal = StudentID

End Function
```

You can call the function like so:

```
Sub theFunction
   getPayTotal 21

   ''Or
   Call getPayTotal(21)

   ''Or
   r = getPayTotal(21)
End Sub
```

In other words, be careful with the parentheses.

Comment: So in functions there's no return, and instead I should treat the function name as a variable, and at End Function, the value the function gives is the variable?

Comment: I guess that covers it. Life can get a little more interesting with objects.

Comment: So I was overlooking something simple. I was confused because the language reference I was looking at used return in a function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s.aspx

Am I looking at the wrong reference? If so I can dig around to try and find the correct one. Thanks. I tried to upvote, but don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: @user2004245  - that's the reference for VB.net, which is a different language from VBA (although the syntax is similar...)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Tim, I'll dig around for the correct reference.

Comment: I knew I had one somewhere http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264383.aspx :)